# WebApp Proxy to APIGEE

Tags: apigee

We have a legacy "Web application" that uses traditional J2EE MVC architecture. The web application is like a thin proxy that does request validation and transformation, calls back-end services, and finally transform the response payload before returning it to the caller. We are planning to move this application to the APIGEE. Since most of my web app code is written in Java, I am planning to use Java callout to perform everything that is being done in my existing "Web App". What I wanted to know is - Are there any other way to migrate the "Web App" logic in the APIGEE proxies? Any experiences you can share?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the transformations necessary, you can refactor to use Apigee native mediation policies and JS, maintaining the JS code directly inside a JS policy in the proxy package. Else call-out to proper Java. It might be lower effort in the short-term to just hang onto your Java and call-out to it, but you may find better performance in the long term if you refactor.